# How to run tests in multiple environments (qa-dev) in TestParallel class and have results in one report?

Tags: karate

We have QA and DEV environment in our automation repo. We are using karate as our framework. We have TestParallel class and integrated allure report.

How could we run all tests in QA first then in DEV back to back using TestParallel Class and see the results in the same report?

- Thanks for such a great tool btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to try and make this easier in the next version.

For now, you have to aggregate the reports yourself. Can you try this and let us know how it goes.

- use the `Runner` class 2 times to run your tests with different settings and `karate.env` set for `QA` and then `DEV`
- the important part is using a different value for the `workingDir`, e.g. `target/reports/qa` and then `target/reports/dev` - else the second run will overwrite the first
- now when generating the HTML report, you can provide `target/reports` as the source folder. this should work for the Maven Cucumber Reports, for Allure, please figure this out on your own
- if the above approach does not work well enough for your needs, please figure out a way to manually aggregate the `Results` object you get from each instance of the `Runner`, this should not be too complicated as Java code